# how to manage todo list in reactjs with localstorage

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TodoList = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []);
    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState('');

    const addTodo = () => {
        if (newTodo.trim() !== '') {
            setTodos([...todos, { id: Date.now(), text: newTodo, completed: false }]);
            setNewTodo('');
        }
    };

    const deleteTodo = (id) => {
        setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
    };

    const updateTodo = (id) => {
        setTodos(
            todos.map((todo) =>
                todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
            )
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    }, [todos]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Todo List</h2>
            <ul>
                {todos.map((todo) => (
                    <li key={todo.id}>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={todo.completed}
                            onChange={() => updateTodo(todo.id)}
                        />
                        <span style={{ textDecoration: todo.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none' }}>
                            {todo.text}
                        </span>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={newTodo}
                    onChange={(e) => setNewTodo(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button onClick={addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted. Minimum 20 characters.

Answer (score 2):

if im understanding you correctly, you want a 20 character minimum for creating a new todo.

it depends on how far you want to take this, you can implement a form validation system, or, for something at this scale, adding another state for an error should do the trick.

in the future, i recommend adding some more information so its clear what the problem is, and how we can help.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []);
const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState('');
const [error, setError] = useState('');

const addTodo = () => {
    if (newTodo.trim().length < 20) {
        setError('Todo must be at least 20 characters long.');
    } else {
        setTodos([...todos, { id: Date.now(), text: newTodo, completed: false }]);
        setNewTodo('');
        setError(''); // Reset error state on successful addition
    }
};

const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
};

const updateTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos(
        todos.map((todo) =>
            todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
        )
    );
};

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]);

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Todo List</h2>
        {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
        <ul>
            {todos.map((todo) => (
                <li key={todo.id}>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={todo.completed}
                        onChange={() => updateTodo(todo.id)}
                    />
                    <span style={{ textDecoration: todo.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none' }}>
                        {todo.text}
                    </span>
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={newTodo}
                onChange={(e) => setNewTodo(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```